# How to convert an integer array into string in javascript without losing the square bracket

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

I want to access object property. i m not able to access key value without single quotes around the array. when i put single quotes manually it returns value. but how to get single quotes placed automatically. is there any function in java script. if i convert to string using String() function i lose the square bracket. Here is my code:

```
var seen = {'[7, 6]': '[0, 0]'}
function getParent(childState){
        //"""return parent of state, if it exists"""
        if(childState in seen){ return seen[childState]; }
        else{ return undefined; }
};
getParent([7, 6]);
```

Comment: `seen` is a key value pair. `'[7, 6]'` is the key and `'[0, 0]'` is the value. So it will work only if you pass key as `'[7, 6]'`

Comment: You'll have to add the brackets manually, and also account for the space, kind of like `'['+[7,6].join(', ')+']'`

Comment: thanks musa it works adding brackets mannually.. but it looks weird

Comment: @AmalHashim i seek a simpler way to do that. if i convert to string i lose square brackets and the spacing between the integers

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a property accessor, you need to provide a string. That means that the *keys* in your `seen` object need to be in a string format. If you want to interact with getParent() using arrays, then you should translate the parameter into a string first. But the values in your `seen` object can still be arrays.

```
var seen = {'7,6': [0, 0]}
function getParent(childState){
    var key = childState.toString();
    return seen[key];
};
getParent([7, 6]);
```

Comment: is there any simple way to convert [7, 6] to '[7, 6]' @StriplingWarrior

Comment: @SudheeshKs: Yes, but I don't understand why you'd want to: '[' + childState.join(', ') + ']'

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if you are beign passed an array and manually build the string key

```
if(typeof childState =="object"){
   childstate = "[" + childState.toString() + "]";
}
```